# logging errors and iexpress wizard

Tags: c#, .net

I've attached a pair of DLL files (about 10) and the resulting exe file into one containing the whole exe file using the IExpress Wizard. In my program, I log errors using the log4net library. Before packing (that is, as Visual Studio creates in the Release version), login works correctly and a file with logs (application.log) is created. However, after 'packing' it all into one thing, everything works fine apart from creating a log file. I checked in the temporary Windows folder to which the project is 'unpacked', all DLLs are there and the original exe file, however, this log file is missing. The project is written in WPF. What did I do wrong?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Just a suggestion, run the project locally and change the log4net logging directory to the temporary Windows folder, and see if it logs. It might be that log4net does not have access rights to write to the temp dir.

Comment: I guess this is right. I changed a directory of log files from exe folder to overriding folder (one higher in folders hierarchy) and log file is created. Thanks for helps!